# Finding the the matrix $(sI-A)^{-1} $

Tags: matrices, inverse, matlab, symbolic-computation

I'm using octave and I wonder how I can compute the matrix $(sI-A)^{-1} $ if $s $ is a symbolic variable and $A $ is a matrix.

Comment: If $A=sI$ then the inverse may not defined...

Comment: Have you tried `inv`?

Comment: Symbolically you will not do much better than the geometric series.

Comment: @Legoman I'd assume $A$ is  a real or complex matrix that does not contain the symbolic variable $s$.

Comment: @quid yes A is a real matrix. I is the identity matrix. Only s is a symbolic variable.

Comment: Use the adjugate matrix.

Comment: I can tell y'all want I really want to do. I want to find the transfer function matrix $G_m(s) = C (sI-A)^{-1}B+D $. And a transfer function look like this $$G(s)  = \frac{s + 2}{s^2 + 3s + 6} $$ something like that.

Comment: Most improtant for me is to find the numerators and denomerator.

Comment: As @RodrigodeAzevedo suggested, google "adjugate matrix". I am pretty sure that you will find something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB you can do it the following way, I think that should also work for Octave but I am not quite sure:

```
% Define matrix A
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

% Define symbolic variable s
syms s;

% evaluate (sI-A)^(-1)
(s*eye(size(A,1))-A)^(-1)

% get denominator
det(s*eye(size(A,1))-A)
```

An alternative way without using the symbolic toolbox is to define a state space model and then use ss2tf.

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
B = [1;1;4];
C = [1 0 0];
D = [0];
[num,den] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not have the symbolic package and not MATLAB. I'm only trying to get the matrix. Can't I assume that $s $ is a really large number? Then divide the whole matrix with the large number ?

Comment: It seems like you can download it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472486/how-do-i-declare-a-symbolic-matrix-in-octave#2596216.

Comment: no, that package is very slow. It must be a way to get the numerators and denomerators from the matrix.

Comment: I used http://octave-online.net/ and it took 4 seconds.

Comment: Yes. But I'm not going to use the symbolic package. I only need to solve this  $G_m(s)  = C (sI-A)^{-1}B+D$ and $G_m(s)$ will contain numerators and denomerators. All matrecies are known. My goal is to convert a MIMO state space model to MIMO transfer function matrix $G_m(s)$

Comment: Added an alternative for this procedure. Next time you should be more precise in your question formulation. Your tags are stating symbolic-computation and now you are stating that you don't want to use the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: I accepted this answer because you answered the right thing on my question, even if I didin't solve my problem.  The function ss2tf works. But I still don't have matlab. I think that ss2tf are using  canonical forms. And those are for SISO case only.

Comment: I don't think that ss2tf is only for SISO systems, it should also work for MIMO.

Comment: Ok. But I don't have MATLAB. My goal is to transform SS to TF and vice versa. I can do it by Octave when it comes to SISO case. Then I use the connocial forms. Do you think that system identification will solve my problem ? If I have a SS mimo model and I identify the poles and zeros. Then I use them to get my TF model ?

Comment: Are you sure that Octave doesn't have ss2tf? https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/ss2tf.html

Comment: I have tried that library. Great library. But not good for MIMO systems.